# ¿Como puedo agregar los datos de la listview2 en la DataTable de la tapPage2? ej: Agregar a Pablo López en la columna nombre, así como la acción

Tags: c#, formularios

[image: Formulario, con un item ingresado en el listview2]
[image: DataGridView con columnas hechas con DataTable]

código del botón registrar:

//Aquí está el código del boton registrar, el cual debe de agregar las acciones a la DataTable, el problema es que no sé como poder pasar los datos que se registren en el ListView2, a la Tabla de la TabPage2, en mi mente la idea es que con un ciclo for puedan registrarse las acciones de todos los jugadores y presentarse a manera de resumen en el DataTable.

//Ej: Si yo tengo a Juan Pérez en el ListView2, necesito que en el DataTable aparezca registrado los goles que hizo, las tarjetas amarillas y si tuvo tarjeta roja, todos esos datos se acumulan en el lisview, pero no sé como proyectarlos en el DataTable.

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string registro = "";

```
        if (this.radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            registro = "Tarjeta roja";
        }
        else if (this.radioButton4.Checked)
        {
            registro = "Tarjeta amarilla";
        }
        else
        {
            registro = "Gol";
        }

        if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            ListViewItem lista;
            lista = new ListViewItem(this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            lista.SubItems.Add(registro);
            this.listView2.Items.Add(lista);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seleccione un jugador de la alineación", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        string nombre = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        DataRow fila = miTabla.NewRow();
        fila["Nombre"] = nombre;

        miTabla.Rows.Add(fila);

    }
```

Comment: quieres mover todos los datos de tu  listview? o solo el que selecciones